# Run VueJS app on Localhost

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, vue.js, localhost

I've bee trying to run a simple VueJS application built with Vue CLI/Webpack into my localhost without having to use npm run dev, but only by accessing from my local server. I ran the npm run build and dragged the files into my htdocs on Mamp, but still it doesnt seem to work. This is my directory structure in the project:

[image]

[image]

This is my index.html in my root folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the index.html in the dist folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>demo</title>
  <link href=/static/css/app.e1c36c05dd8e70649268723708cfb519.css rel=stylesheet>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js>
  </script><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.3fae27b6d0a0572472a3.js></script>
  <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.e5eb3a5fa6134479362c.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am i missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you transfer the `build` folder? If so, that's the wrong folder. Your built files is under `dist`

Comment: Also, are you using router?

Comment: Yes i am using router @SølveTornøe

Comment: I transfered everything that is in there. Do i need to get ride of the folder or transfer into the dist?@SølveTornøe

Comment: Once you build your project, the only thing you need to transfer over to your http-server is the content of the dist folder. In your case, the folder `static/` and `index.html`

Comment: However, regarding the router. I remember having an issue like this way back. When I built the files with router and transferred the files, it only displayed a blank page. If I changed to non-router, it worked. I think the issue was something with my .htaccess file, but I cannot remember.

Comment: What do you mean @Helpinghand? The content of the main.js or scripts from App.vue?

Comment: Why would you not one to use npm dev?

Comment: Because this is not the case when on production, right? I was thinking of when taking this small dev app into a production envinronment @TheBlackBenzKid

Comment: That would be npm run though? I was just curious. I normally copy my folder and view the source code and find the paths need updating - including base href injection - this normally works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1 - `npm run build`

2 - copy the build dist folder or dist with `index.html`

3 - make a new folder in htdocs `test`

4 - go to `localhost/test`

If things don't work view source in a text editor and change paths of your src files and maybe add a base href. Your code shows `/static/`

I would replace

```
<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.e5eb3a5fa6134479362c.js></script>
```

This to

```
<script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost/test/static/js/app.e5eb3a5fa6134479362c.js"></script>
```

Also check console errors.

Comment: you dont have to look for `/static/` just use the full url for any file that is referenced, even the icon

Answer (score 0):

Is it like a blank page? did you get any error in the console?

I think it's because it doesn't know where the root index file is.

**Try:

- Go to the "htdocs folder" and create an empty folder(example folder name: abc).

- Go to "config folder" in your project.

- Inside of the "config folder" there is a js file called index.js

- inside of index.js change the "assetsPublicPath" path under build, default only has '/'. Change it to '/abc/' and run npm build after that put all the file that are generate from build inside of that folder, it should know where to find the root index file.

- Go to http://localhost/abc/**

Comment: How am i supose to run in an external folder? index.js to an external folder in the htdocs???

Comment: no only change the path in the index.js(index.js in your project which is in the config folder), after that run "npm run build" and it will generate new files inside of the "dist" folder, move every files in the dist folder to the empty folder that you created inside of the "htdocs" folder.

Comment: And remember only change the "assetsPublicPath" path under build, not under dev.

Comment: I know, i just did it. It doesnt work. It must be something else. Thanks